# Show Twitch.tv stream within a unity3D application

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, twitch

I would like to make an Unity3D Application in which one can watch a current Twitch.tv live stream.

I am not sure if this is possible, for example, with the twitch api (https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api)

I know about the video textures in Unity3D and I know how to use the default twitch api basics but I do not have an idea how to integrate a running twitch stream into my application.

Can someone please give me a hint if this is possible?

Thanks very much and best regards
Meph

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately the stream coming from twitch is MPEG-4 (H264/M3U). So if you can render that in Unity, then you can render twitch streams.

There's a few steps to get the right URLs requested from twitch, and that can change over time.  You'll have to inspect a current twitch page while a stream is playing to see how the javascript builds the request (url and headers).

In the end, the javascript will build an access token then use it to request a file called `index-live.m3u8` from one of the twitch edge servers.  That file contains a list of files names for the last few seconds of the live stream (and some other meta data).  It looks something like this

https://video-edge-c61b44.lax01.hls.ttvnw.net/v0/[some-long-access-token]/index-live.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#ID3-EQUIV-TDTG:2017-10-27T16:53:27
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:8788
#EXT-X-TWITCH-ELAPSED-SECS:17576.000
#EXT-X-TWITCH-TOTAL-SECS:17589.870
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008788-Y6OH.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008789-l0QY.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008790-gCUV.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008791-1ngg.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008792-wpQL.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
index-0000008793-koO4.ts
```

You then swap out `index-live.m3u8` with the name of a file in the list and request it to get that clip.  Something like:

https://video-edge-c61b44.lax01.hls.ttvnw.net/v0/[the-same-long-access-token]/index-0000008793-koO4.ts

It will be an MPEG-4 stream about 1 second long.  The list is about 6 files long, so if you request them all you can get about a 6 second buffer.

Every second or two, index-live.m3u8 is updated and older files roll off as new ones are added to the bottom.  You need to re-request this file every few seconds as your buffer runs out, and request the new clips in it to keep your playback going.

Answer (score 1):

using Ted Bigham's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980312/8628766) you can get the m3u8 stream of the video. You can then feed this stream into a plugin like [AVPro video from Renderheads](http://renderheads.com/product/avpro-video/) to play it directly in unity on any shape or model you want, with a wide variety of customisation and settings.

However this is not a free plugin, and there may be alternatives. I am in no way affiliated to them, but have used this plug-in in the past with good results.

p.s i originally wanted to post this as just a comment, and believe Ted Bigham answered the grunt of your question. But am not allowed due to reputation.

Answer (score 1):

@Ted Bigham is there anyway to do this just using the default unity video player?

Everything you've said so far has worked great! With just chrome, I'm able to open the `.m3u8` and download each 1 second `.ts` file. With just any video player, I can view each video file just fine.

When I try to pass the url through Video Player though, it says "Cannot read file." I even tried replacing `.ts` with `.mp4` since that is a supported format. This works when I test it outside of Unity, but gives me the same error.

Here's my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class TwitchStreamer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string m3u8 = "https://video-weaver.atl01.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/Cq4EuEYkh5IqurC4gy3nHqGhPVtUwH_" +
        "5QcQbCatC5Fhit9qbivMQ2rdh2MS_m_2OuLd3VS2mF0eTrCKrz8YTuDO19mcbIBMJL3BUMz4jnNuU_t-e53V51TOtaN3vcCk9n3Qr" +
        "dP0WyLREnVR0n_30d4PlUjjW4_si5Wr2XuePQ0dPtxP6jnsenKnX56YTLohtCN2-FdfSvHQMdfd0aw68FA4h9wawHoIM9-U6YRmPa" +
        "fDsfdCiZr_iToSR6lZi81VoYPVjt7Ygf7xKwhjlNwrvA5SnsAnWQGIOVt4UjDkNLw-hmNMAr7RT0iiDghKXZY1VI6Tuc-umB1VXYE" +
        "7BH5hHbDfHgB3_IYNb0fjoudtSuaZxISyWoazPrw3AibEO7k1-quhdcjarBTGpIi_dlPEp-yZlQOy98_OZY_tqjk8ZWTBIaAAYEG_" +
        "miwqsgH4d6eIfkh3ehyMvPQH1C5dVG9tQcSWPUYU6D6hWhxvJhEr-UC0_BYWIVzX7z_Uf74FJGIEqSQc0d6igiowdMM_lyD8ZV9BE" +
        "7wqQs3RegMPqux-AOfF-_Q7Ki2MBv9u7D9ZRXMH_cm20bTx5-ShEDRnWMApSfXK-9bAGNXUcw8YlBbHYeSN5VxEZMC2oGjcivBsGs" +
        "RPMTQ_yNBSM1S6GxFRIR4nqA-mbdXg3rXMW3V6MNybBb1lrrQeEqF1tdYE0rfxe3Ki5WWkxeKmSjMGbMl1tHCwMaReTYkQnX5Qhjl" +
        "HXXtKLtEIEEhB3cXW3oF05-E_q87s68JQIGgyIEKPiQlTsANR9zRc.m3u8";


    public float updateClip = 1f, updateFile = 6f;

    public VideoPlayer vp;

    Queue<string> urls;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(UpdateFile());
        //InvokeRepeating("UpdateFile", 0f, updateFile);
        InvokeRepeating("UpdateClip", updateClip, updateClip);
        urls = new Queue<string>();
        vp.prepareCompleted += Vp_prepareCompleted;
        vp.errorReceived += Vp_errorReceived;
    }

    private void Vp_errorReceived(VideoPlayer source, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("4567: Playback preparation failed. " + message, source);
    }

    private void Vp_prepareCompleted(VideoPlayer source)
    {
        Debug.Log("4567: Playback preparation complete.");
        source.Play();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        StopAllCoroutines();
        vp.prepareCompleted -= Vp_prepareCompleted;
        vp.errorReceived -= Vp_errorReceived;
    }

    void UpdateClip()
    {
        //vp.Stop();
        if (urls.Count > 0)
        {
            vp.url = urls.Dequeue();
            vp.Prepare();
            Debug.Log("4567: Prepare playback for " + vp.url);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateFile()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(m3u8);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            //Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            string[] raw = www.downloadHandler.text.Split('\n');
            foreach (string line in raw)
            {
                if (line.Contains("http"))
                {
                    string cnvrt = line.Replace(".ts", ".mp4");
                    urls.Enqueue(cnvrt);
                    Debug.Log(line + " has been added to stream queue.");
                }
            }
            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            //byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(updateFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what this person wants to know is whether or not the Twitch API actually retrieves a live video feed and passes the data through to the application. The short answer is, it doesn't. The Twitch API doesn't allow you to take a live video feed, only get the information about it.

You can get strings telling you the name of the channel, the game and links to take you to the channel. You can also get their channel background or previews as image files. What you cannot do is get video files or stream video data. The best you can do is get the URLs and link to them.

The only method I can think of to get a Live Stream in any game is for it to be the player's. Essentially you would code in a method by which they can stream their game within the game itself, taking the stream data and copying it into some variable or class somewhere, before it is uploaded to Twitch, so you can use the data at the same time it is being broadcast. But if you want to retrieve some random streamer's gameplay and display it on a computer screen in your game, I'm afraid you can't do that. Not in Unity, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- You can embed a twitch stream into a website
- There are web browser plugins for Unity([see](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/55459))

So if you combine these ideas, you can show a twitch stream in unity by running an in-app browser that will run a custom web page which embed the stream that you want. I don't know what kind of performance you'll get out of this but that sounds simple enough to do. It probably is not as simple as directly showing the stream on a texture but it's at least simpler than learning C, network programming, video processing and etc like Thomas suggested.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky thing to do. You would need an API key from Twitch, a program that can establish not only a connection with your chosen API, but also a data stream. I would suggest starting with learning basic network programming in a less specialized language like C, and work from there. After you understand the basics, please come back and ask more specific questions. I can't do that much with this question in the state that it's in.

As with everything else, this is definitely possible, just maybe not with C#. For the sake of not destroying your game's performance, I would suggest writing a separate program that feeds the data into the game without the game directly grabbing data.

Once you gain an understanding of network programming, I would hop over to the twitch dev chat on the API, found [here](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/c/api)